# Ant, get directiores names from remote machine

Tags: ant, directory, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ant, download fileset from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191713/ant-download-fileset-from-remote-machine)

How to get folder names from specified directory in remote machine using ant?

Comment: Unix? Windows? Is SSH an option?

Comment: SSH in ant. But it would be great if I wouldn't need to do anything with ssh keys. Aaand second thing I'd like to say that this topic  IS NOT a duplicate. It is about getting folders names and save it for example in text file. Something like ls > temp.txt. Nothing to download...

Comment: Ant script launched from Windows, remote machine is linux. I'd like not to use ssh.

Comment: This is the solution, file with listed directories is sent to dir on my local machine: http://pastebin.com/ytKCghYD (I wish I could reply in this topic, but it is locked and this is ridicolous.)