# ANT script to copy a source file from server to local folder

Tags: windows, ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ant, download fileset from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191713/ant-download-fileset-from-remote-machine)

I have Folders in specified Path Server that has to be copied to specified Path in local.. How to achieve this in ant script?

```
local filename C:/project
Server name   : //pmfvc/04/
```

in that server directory I need to copy only javasource directory.

Comment: Try ant ftp [tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html)

Comment: A more cross platform solution would use the ANT scp task. It appears you are looking for a windows solution? The best way to enable remote downloading is to install an SSH server on the remote machine.  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html