# Syncing local and remote directories using rsync+ssh+public key as a user different to the ssh key owner

Tags: unix, deployment, permissions, ssh, rsync

The goal is to sync local and remote folders over ssh.

My current user is *user1*, and I have a password-less access setup over ssh to a server *server1*. 
I want to sync local folder with a folder on *server1* by means of **rsync** utility.
Normally I would run:

```
rsync -rtvz /path/to/local/folder server1:/path/to/remote/folder
```

**ssh** access works as expected, **rsync** is able to connect over **ssh**, but it returns "Permission denied" error because on *server1* the folder `/path/to/remote/folder` is owned by *user2*:*user2*. File permissions of the folder do not allow it to be altered by anyone else. 
*user1* is a sudoer on *server1* so `sudo su - user2` works during **ssh** session.
How to forse **rsync** to switch the user when it **ssh**'ed to the server?

Adding *user1* to the group *user2* is not an option because all user/group management on the server is done automatically and replicated from a central repo every X mins, that I have not access to.

Same for changing permissions/ownership of the destination folder: it is updated automatically on a regular basis with a reset of all permissions.

Possible solution coming to my mind is a script that syncs the local folder with a temporary intermediate remote folder owned by *user1* on the server, and then syncs two remotes folders as *user2*.

Googling for a shorter and prettier solution did not yield any success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried it by myself, but how about using rsync's '--rsync-path' option?

```
rsync -rtvz --rsync-path='sudo -u user2 rsync' /path/to/local/folder server1:/path/to/remote/folder
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Works as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the permissions problem you need to run rsync over an an SSH session that logs in remotely as user2:

```
rsync avz -e 'ssh -i privatekeyfile' /path/to/local/folder/ user2@server1:/path/to/local/folder
```

The following answer explains how to setup the SSH keys.

- [Ant, download fileset from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191713/ant-download-fileset-from-remote-machine/12206460#12206460)

Comment: There is no permissions problem. _user1_ has SSH keys set up and _user1_ is a sudoer on the remote machine. So potentially _user1_ has all needed privileges to perform rsync task.

Comment: @schatten It is a permissions issue. By default rsync will not use sudo as your accepted answer has demonstrated. Actually it's quite clever how rsync can be adapted in this way!

Answer (score 0):

Set up password-less access for *user1* to access *user2@server1*, then do:

```
rsync -rtvz /path/to/local/folder user2@server1:/path/to/remote/folder
```

Comment: Do you mean adding _user1_'s public key to the list of authorized ssh keys of _user2_? If yes, those get overwritten as well.