# How to rsync and preserve owner of files at destination

Tags: permissions, rsync, su

I would like to use rsync via ssh to copy files from *source-machine* to *dest-machine* (both Linux boxes). Due to a security policy that is beyond my control, the files on *dest-machine* must be owned by *user1* but *user1* is not allowed to log in. I am *user2* and can log in via ssh to both machines, *user2* is in the same group as *user1*, and both users exist on both machines. After logging into either machine *user1* can become *user2* by first doing *sudo -s* (no password prompt) and then *su user1*.

The files typically have the following permissions:

```
source-machine:
-rw-rw-r-- user2  group1  file.txt

dest-machine:
-rw-rw-r-- user1  group1  file.txt
```

Rsync always changes the ownership on *dest-machine* to be user2, becuase I am using

```
/usr/bin/rsync -rlvx --delete --exclude-from ignore-file.txt --rysnc-path="/usr/bin/rsync" /path/to/files/ -e ssh user2@dest-machine.example.com:/path/to/files/
```

as part of the rsync command. At the moment, I have to work out which files have been copied and change the ownership back to *user1*.

I saw in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351190/syncing-local-and-remote-directories-using-rsyncsshpublic-key-as-a-user-differ) that it may be possible to use

```
--rsync-path='sudo -u user2 rsync'
```

but I need the intermediate step of *sudo -s*.

Is there a way to get rsync to leave the files on *dest-machine* owned by *user1*?

UPDATE: Thanks to mnagel's comment, I tried that permutation, and when that didn't work, I was exploring why and added two more permutations: (1) I ran the script at *source-machine* as root and (2) I had somehow not included -go as options. (I hadn;t used -a, as the security policy doesn't allow preserving times). When put altogether, it works.

Comment: assuming the mentioned discussion is right: have you tried `--rsync-path='sudo sudo -u user2 rsync'?