# scp ant copy from remote to local and use excludes

Tags: ant, scp

I am trying to copy files in remote serve to local using `scp` task in `ant`. The thing is, I want to exclude certain files with extension `*.txt`, so I tried using `excludes` tag. But it seems not to work. And It copies all the files including the files with extension `*.txt`

```
<scp file="username:pwd@remotemachine:/path/to/files/*" todir="copycontent" trust="true">
     <fileset dir="files" >
         <exclude name="**/*.txt"/>
     </fileset>
</scp>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ant [SCP](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) task has some limitations for your scenario:

- "FileSet only works for copying files from the local machine to a remote machine." (from the Ant SCP manual page)
- The SCP element itself does not provide attributes for includes/excludes patterns

So options for selective copying from remote to local are limited. More flexibility for copying from local to remote (using fileset).

Rather than excluding `*.txt`, you could instead include one or more file patterns one or more scp blocks.

Or an alternative if the local system is unix-based could be to exec rsync, as suggested in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206460/127035).

Comment: when I remove the file attribute, I get a error message `'todir' and 'file' attributes must have syntax like the following: user:password@host:/path`