# Compare time-stamp of a remote file with a local file using Ant

Tags: linux, ant, ftp

I have an installer file on my remote machine with **Installer-000.zip** name and i want to copy that file into my local machine(linux-CentOS) under **/media/Data/Installer/** directory using ant **ftp** task.

I am able to copy the installer from remote server to my machine if the installer is not already present in my machine but when i again run the build.xml it downloads the heavy installer file again on my local machine which makes the whole building time much longer.

so esentially i want to comapre the time-stamp of my installer(remote) with one on my local machine and copy from remote to local if the installer file present on remote machine has a newer time-stamp.

(Obviously I want an ant task to do this. I am using ant-version 1.9.6 )

any suggestion or comments would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried? What does your ant task look like so far?

Comment: This is working for me to fetch the installer


<target name="fetch-Installer" description="fetch remote installer" >
  <mkdir dir="${installer.dir}" />

  <ftp action="get"
   server="server_name"
   userid="userID"
   password="passwd"
   remotedir="/installers/">


   <fileset dir="${installer.dir}">

    <include name="${installer.file.name}"/>

   </fileset>


  </ftp>


 </target>

Comment: apology for poor formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an ANT task that will calculate the checksum of a remote file. I suggest a different approach of using rsync over ssh.

[Ant, download fileset from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191713/ant-download-fileset-from-remote-machine/12206460#12206460)